# Angular & RxJS: How to manage errors from services to component

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

I have an ApiService that aims at sending requests to a Rest Server. It is used by several ComponentServices to restrieve and send data from/to server

Ex: UsernewComponent & UserlistComponent use userService which uses apiService.

I would like to transmit errors from services to the end components to be able to show a modal or something when error occur.

But I do not manage it...

Thank you for your help !
NB: as I am new to Angular & Rxjs, If you see something in my code that can be better, please tell me ;-)

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private baseEndpoint = 'http://myurl/projserver/api/';
  private maxTime = 5000;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getEntriesFromRest (option: string): any {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.baseEndpoint + option)
        .pipe(
            timeout(this.maxTime),
            catchError(this.handleError),
            map((data) => data['hydra:member'])
        );
  }

  public getEntryFromRest (option: string): any {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseEndpoint + option)
        .pipe(
            timeout(this.maxTime),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Client-side errors
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // Server-side errors
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { User } from '../models/User.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  private users: User[] = [];
  private usersSubject = new Subject<User[]>();
  usersSubject$ = this.usersSubject.asObservable(); 

  private user: User;
  private userSubject = new Subject<User>();
  userSubject$ = this.userSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  emitUsers() {
    this.usersSubject.next(this.users.slice());
  }

  emitUser() {
    this.userSubject.next(this.user);
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    this.users.push(user);
    this.emitUsers();
  }

  editUser(user: User) {
    var index = this.users.findIndex((item) => item.id === user.id);
    this.users.splice(index, 1, user);
    this.emitUsers();
  }

  getUsersFromRest() {
    this.users=[];
    this.apiService.getEntriesFromRest('users').subscribe(
    (data: any[]) => { data.forEach( (item: User) => {
            this.users.push(item);});
            this.emitUsers();
        },
    (error) => {
            console.log('UserService: '+error);
            this.userSubject.next(error);
            return throwError(error);
        });
  }

  getUserFromRest(userId: number) {
    this.apiService.getEntryFromRest('users/'+userId).subscribe(
        (data: User) => {
            this.user=data;
            this.emitUser();
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('UserService: '+error);
            this.userSubject.next(error);
            return throwError(error);
        }
    );
  }

}
```

usernew.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { User } from '../../../models/User.model';
import { Role } from '../../../models/Role.model';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';
import { MustMatch } from '../../../validators/must-match.validator';
import { NbDialogService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { DialogComponent } from '../../../components/dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'usernew',
  templateUrl: './usernew.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usernew.component.scss']
})
export class UsernewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  userIdSubscription: Subscription;
  userSubscription: Subscription;
  user: User;

...

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private userService: UserService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private nbDialogService: NbDialogService
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.userSubscription = this.userService.userSubject$.subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        if (user) {
            this.user = user;           
            this.editUser(this.user);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
            console.log('Component: '+error);   
        }
    );
    this.userIdSubscription = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        const userId = +params.get('id');           //cast to number
        if(userId) {
            this.view='Edit';
            this.loading = true;
            this.userService.getUserFromRest(userId);
        }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userIdSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

...
}
```

userlist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../../models/User.model';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'userlist',
  templateUrl: './userlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userlist.component.scss']
})
export class UserlistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...
  users: User[] = [];
  usersSubscription: Subscription;
  loading = false;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersSubscription = this.userService.usersSubject$.subscribe(
      (users: User[]) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("Userlist Component: "+error);
    }
    );
    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.getUsersFromRest();
    //this.userService.emitUsers();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.usersSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

...

}
```

Comment: So, you say you cold not manage it. What does it mean ? Nothing prints in the console.log ? Is there another issue ?

Comment: the userService console.log('UserService: '+error); works but not the components console.log errors

Answer (score 0):

You implemented `ApiService` to provide some common behaviour to all your http calls:
- timeout
- error handling

It's OK but you still have to remember to use this service in each and every one of your other services. Plus you still have to handle errors in your 'real' services.

I advise you to use to use `HttpInterceptor` to implement this knd of common behaviour.
You can find some valuable informations here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6

Comment: I already uses interceptor for jwt token insertion in header (NbAuthJWTInterceptor), is it a problem or can I use several interceptors?

Comment: You can use as many interceptors as you want, because they are chained together. AS the documentation says: "Angular applies interceptors in the order that you provide them. If you provide interceptors A, then B, then C, requests will flow in A->B->C and responses will flow out C->B->A."

Comment: Ok, so I fI understand correctly, the best way is to remove all my (error) => {} in subscription and treat eventual errors by a global httpInterceptor, Right?